# Text Classifier in Python using Naive Bayes

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I need to write a Python program using Jupyter Notebook to perform text classification using Multinomial Naïve Bayes. The task is to create a dataset of news headlines (only), save them in text files, and name the text file with the category of the news.

The categories you have to handle are: Politics Sports Weather Business You should have 4 text files; Politics.txt, Sports.txt, Weather.txt and Business.txt. Each file should contain at least 100 headlines. Using the skeletal code, your job is to implement a Text Classifier that can classify a headline given by user as a specific Category.

Input: Headline text Output: Category corresponding to the headline
Here is the skeleton code I want to try.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XjIReEbxjcpiHIKJyGvZ3yFF7FcdIk2Z

Comment: You should include the relevant code and a description of the specific problem that you are finding with your code.

Comment: I want it to start it from scratch but dont know how to. Can you please help?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a free code writing service.
Also, please, please, please embed relevant code in the question, not on an external link. This means people looking for similar answers can learn from your issues and the link doesn't go stale (e.g. if you delete the contents to free up space in the future)